# What is wrong with this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the regular expression below however it still seems to match when it should not

```
^article\/article_story\.aspx(\?id\=(?!1211)[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

So effectively if the ID equals to 1211 it should not match and the expression is passed however if it matches say ID 1212 it performs the necesarry task however it still seems to match when the ID is indeed 1211

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://regexr.com?2uam4

Comment: Maybe you should use a regex to extract the ID and then just check if the ID is what you want.

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it works. When id is 1211 the expression does not get matched. As a sidenote, you don't need to escape the equals sign (`=`).

Comment: Also, if it isn't in `.htaccess` or somewhere similar, just use substring or some variable provided by ASP to get the ID and check if it's 1211.

Comment: @Ryan Gross - Thanks. Why would it match and redirect the user then?

Comment: @Francisc - Thanks. Wasn't sure if the operator = was reserved

Comment: @André Puel - What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: what regex engine are you using?

Comment: @Ryan Gross  - I don't follow what you mean by what regex engine am I using?

Comment: where are you evaluating this regular expression (perl, php, shell script, java, c#, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see it matching 1211 : http://regexr.com?2uam7

---

And you are unnecessarily complicating it with a huge regex and the `(!...)`. You can just match the id part ( groups ) and then see if it is not 1211. It is not necessary to do everything in regex.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean exactly?